# Executing command after a for loop in batch file?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that currently does two things, it first goes to a desired directory, then it will run a for statement to delete every file that isn't a certain file, the content of the bat file looks like this:

```
cd "bin\drivers" && for %%i in (*.*) do if not %%i == lol.exe del %%i
```

This works perfectly, but I want to do some other things after this for statement has been executed, something like this:

```
cd "bin\drivers" && for %%i in (*.*) do if not %%i == lol.exe del %%i && cd ../../../ && start server
```

But the problem with this is that while it does execute the statements after the for loop, the for loop is only executed for one iteration, so it only deletes one file and moves onto the next statement in the bat file (which is the cd, and then starting the server). Is there anything I can do so that the statements after the for statement executes after the entire for loop is done instead of just 1 iteration?

Comment: Yes, use more than one line, or parenthesize your single line command, _(there's no need to use a single line, it doesn't speed up your script)_. Also learn the difference between the command concatenator, `&`, and the conditional operator, `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, here's your single line with appropriate use of parentheses and ampersands.

```bat
@CD bin\drivers 2>NUL && ((For %%# In (*) Do @If /I Not "%%#"=="lol.exe" Del "%%#") & CD ..\..\.. 2>NUL && Start server
```

However, I do not see any reason to be changing directories, so this may be simpler:

```bat
@(For %%# In (bin\drivers\*) Do @If /I Not "%%~nx#"=="lol.exe" Del "%%#") & Start ..\server
```

Comment: The second one is exactly what I was looking for! I added it to my file and now it works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. _The second one may have been exactly what you were 'hoping' for, but the first is exactly what you were 'looking' for!_

Answer (score 0):

This will loop first, once the loop is done, it will execute the server only.

```
@echo off
if not exist "bin\drivers" goto :eof
cd /d "bin\drivers"
for %%i in (*) do if not "%%~i" == "lol.exe" del "%%~i"
cd /d ..\..\..\
start server
```